# UITableViewCell show selected when switching Views

Tags: uitableview, selection, highlight

i got a UITableViewCell which i want to stay selected when clicked on it. So i have this code which works just fine:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {   

static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension]];
    //cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [bgColorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
    return cell;
}
```

Everytime i click on a cell it gets selected with the brown color and stays selected until i click another cell... perfect
But when i dismiss the view by clicking on the back button of my navigationcontroller and then i switch back to my view my cell is not selected anymore. So how can i achieve that the cell which was selected before i switched the views still is selected when i come back to the view ?

I thought i maybe have to create a property from the tableview and then select the row in the viewDidLoad again. The selectedRow index i could save in the nsuserdefaults.. but i hope there is a simpler solution.

Comment: nobody ? please i really need your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `-viewDidLoad` method, add this to the bottom: `self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;` Which would make it look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
}
```

Comment: but i dont have a uitableviewcontroller, i am in a uiviewcontroller